# Table and Table-cell working differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm working on [**this**](http://media.firm.in/rwpnewsite/) website.

If you open it on **Chrome** everything is displayed as intended.

At the **footer** of the website, you will see 8 logos which fit perfectly.
If you open it using **Mozilla Firefox**, the logo list extends beyond the website container.

Below are the 2 pictures -

**Chrome :**
[image]1

**Firefox :**
[image]

The logos are inside a `ul` as list items

and the CSS is like this

```
.clients ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.clients ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: You can state that this is not a compatibility issue because the [display table rule on caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) show a perfect interpretation of this property in almost every browser for every versions.

Comment: Exactly, but then why this inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a difference in how the *images'* widths are calculated inside of the table, and not the table elements themselves.

Tables make sure that all content is visible, so if it cannot shrink or wrap its contents then it expands past 100%. Chrome figures out that the images can shrink and adjusts the table width thereafter, while Firefox uses the full widths of the images to calculate the width of the table.

Almost ironically, setting `width: 100%` on the images will force Firefox to behave in the same fashion as Chrome.

**Edit:** As a footnote, your "table" structure isn't completely right. It doesn't seem to cause any layout issues in this particular case, but you should make sure to always have the proper `table > tbody > tr > td` hierarchy to prevent weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

make table-layout: fixed

```
.clients ul{
 table-layout: fixed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want all eight logos in the row you could give them a fixed width of `12.5%`

---

otherwise set

```
.img-responsive{
display: block;
width: 100%;
/*max-width: 100%;*/
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I want all 8 logos inside the container

Comment: actually chrome was fixing the issue  , but I believe the correct behavior is FF's